# hasPairsWithSum Google Interview Question

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, javascript-objects

I solved this problem by iterating through the array then find the item when the sum equals to `array[i] + item` returning true otherwise returning false.

**My Question is**  =>  How I can return the indices of those numbers that add up to sum not just true? Using the same code below:

```
function hasPairsWithSum(array,sum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array.find((item) => {return sum === array[i] + item}
    ));
    return true;
  };
  return false;
};
console.log(hasPairsWithSum([1,2,4,4],8))
```

Note: Time complexity must be less than O(n ^ 2).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript O(n) Solution.

```
function hasPairsWithSum(array, sum) {
  const map = new Map ();
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let currVal = array[i];
    if (map.has(currVal)) {
      return [map.get(currVal),i]
    }
    // difference value = sum - current value
    let diff = sum - currVal
    map.set(diff,i)
  }
};
console.log(hasPairsWithSum([2,2,4,4], 8))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code.

```js
function hasPairsWithSum(array,sum) {
    let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array.some((item, index) => {return i === index ? false : sum === array[i] + item}))
        result.push(i);
  };
  return result;
};
console.log(hasPairsWithSum([1,2,4,4],8))
console.log(hasPairsWithSum([3,2,4],6))
console.log(hasPairsWithSum([0,4,3,0],0))
```

Comment: This will return [0,1].
but the right answer is [2,3]

Comment: ``` ! ``` should be removed.

Comment: Not Working!!!
Test it with nums = [3,2,4] and sum = 6
returns [0,1,2] but the right answer = [1,2]

Comment: Sorry. I have updated.

Comment: You can use Array.some function instead of Array.find function.

Comment: Thanks a lot . One step ahead to an efficient code. array = [0,4,3,0], sum = 0 returns [ ] the right answer [0,3]

Comment: What's mean? This is working as you wanted.

Comment: it works well..

Comment: I hope your work is going well. Please vote!!!

Comment: Yep! sorry I can't.

Comment: Ok. thanks. See you later.

Comment: Nice to meet you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the array elements checking at every iteration for every element of the array (except the last one) all the elements at the right of it like below:

```js
function findIndexes(array, sum) {
    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length -1; ++i) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; ++j) {
            if ((array[i] + array[j]) === sum)  {
                result.push([i, j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(findIndexes([1, 2, 4, 4], 8));
console.log(findIndexes([3, 2, 4], 6));
```

**Update:**

It is possible to obtain a linear *O(n)* complexity using an auxiliary [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map?retiredLocale=it) structure associating an integer value as key with as a value the list containing all the indexes of the elements in the array equal to the integer key like below:

```js
function findIndexes(array, sum) {
    const map = new Map();
    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        const a = array[i];
        const b = sum - a;
        
        if (map.has(b)) {
            for (const index of map.get(b)) {
                result.push([index, i]);
            }
        }
        
        const l = map.has(a) ? map.get(a) : [];
        l.push(i);
        map.set(a, l);      
    }

    return result;
}


console.log(findIndexes([1, 2, 4, 4], 8));
console.log(findIndexes([3, 2, 4], 6));
console.log(findIndexes([1, 1, 1], 2));
```

Comment: This brute solution has a time complexity of (n ^ 2) and that's bad.

Comment: @MoeDevo You are welcome. You haven't talked about complexity in your question, then you can use a `Map` to store the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

**O(n)** Soln  ... using math concept a+b = n  then if a is present in our array then need to find b = n - a is present or not ..

```
def hasPairsWithSum(array,sum):
    d = {} 
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if(array[i] in d):
            d[array[i]].append(i)
        else:
            d[array[i]] = [i]
    ans  = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        val = sum - array[i]
        if(val in d):
            if(d[val][0] == i):
                if(len(d[val])  > 1):
                    ans.append((i,d[val][1]))
                    break
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                ans.append((i,d[val][0]))
                break
    return ans
print(hasPairsWithSum([4, 4, 4, 4], 8))
```

**O(nlogn)** soln ....just store the index with elements .. then sort it by their values .. next step run a loop with complexity of O(n) [concept : Two pointers]

```
def hasPairsWithSum(array,sum):
    arr = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        arr.append((array[i],i))
    arr.sort()
    i = 0
    j = len(array)-1
    ans = []
    while(i<j):
        tmp_sum = arr[i][0] + arr[j][0]
        if(tmp_sum == sum):
            ans.append((arr[i][1] , arr[j][1]))
            #add your logic if you want to find all possible indexes instead of break
            break
        elif(tmp_sum < sum):
            i = i + 1
        elif(tmp_sum > sum):
            j = j - 1
    return ans
print(hasPairsWithSum([1,2,4,4],8))
```

- note : if you want to find all possible soln then these approaches will not work either add you own logic in while loop or another approach is use **binary search** with traversal on every element and store the indexes in set (worst case this will be O(n^2) as we have to find all possible values) Eg: [4,4,4,4,4,4] , sum = 8 and you want to print all possible indexes then we end up running it upto n^2 (why? reason: total possible solns. are 5+4+3+2+1 = n*(n-1)/2 ≈ n^2)

Comment: @MoeDevo if you find any difficulty in programming language ... I will update the code with js.

Comment: Thanks. I can understand your code in python and it works well.

Comment: hey you can do it in O(n) also. @MoeDevo with simple math concept a+b = n ,,, use a map a = n - b (just search if b exists or not)

Comment: @MoeDevo no I will post the O(n+k) soln ... My current soln is O(nlogn) coz of sorting.

Comment: Thanks. I'm testing it.

Comment: Yep. I didn't pay attention to that

Comment: @MoeDevo I'have added the code .. pls have a look

Comment: ... works well in all my test cases.

Comment: @MoeDevo O(n) Soln. as well? Then give some credits bro  .. Just kidding

Comment: I just released that the js code is pretty time consuming because of for loop and some method. O(n^2)

Comment: @MoeDevo Actually All JS  codes below are O(n^2) and your accepted soln of JS is also O(n^2). complexity of array.some() is also in worst case O(n) [i guess maybe i am wrong] which leads to total complexity to O(n^2)

Comment:  Not using it for work. I'm learing data structures and algorithms

Comment: @MoeDevo   okay .. I thought you have given the interview (however these que. will not be asked directly in an interview).

Comment: No . This question is from 2016 and it is posted on YT. I'm trying to improve problem soving skills by solving those kinds of questions. However I've solved the question in js with O(n) and I'm gonna post it

Comment: @MoeDevo ohh yeah great ...

Comment: I used hash map to solve it. 
Iterating over the array getting the current value then subtract from the sum to get the difference and setting them to the map if map has current value it will get the current value and its index. you can review it if you want

Comment: @MoeDevo nice soln.. .. your O(n) mine O(n) solns. are same but your one is better than mine (complicated).. just accept your soln.(voted)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. have a nice day.